# How to retrieve real time changes from Firestore document in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to work with realtime changes in firebase.
I found [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) but it only applies to collections. I'd like to grab data from a single document.

The sample code is below, how should I change it in order to refer to a document?

```dart
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
}

class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['full_name']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['company']),
                );
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dabbel I found a working solutions with StreamBuilder, could you check my own answer? Do you think it's correct? I thought FutureBuilder was for One Time read, I need realtime changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution, it seems working

```dart
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(documentId).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(" Full name ${data['Full name']} ");

        }


      )
```

Comment: This indeed looks correct: a `DocumentReference` has a `snapshots()` method too, just like a `CollectionReference` and `Query`. So listening to a document is pretty similar to listen to multiple documents, with the differene being in the argument passed to your `Builder`. 

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Perfect, thanks for confirming that!